# JS Functions firing per click, counting click, and in order of

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to organize my JS functions to occur, neatly, `onClick` ONE after another. Currently they are all firing out of order and scrambled; as opposed to **Click = 1 does this; and Click = 2 does this**. Any pointers? Below is my JS. The full demo link can be seen at: 'http://bit.ly/10BW89N'. You can see what I mean by visiting my demo and noticing the clicks don't follow in order of 1,2,3,4 etc - throughout.

**Click the nailhead**, notice click 3 abruptly skips to click 8. I am trying to do this so I can easily add functions per the specific click number. *EG. 30th click, last click, does something really really cool* But it has to fire on the 30th click, rather then something like the 3rd as it defeats the purpose.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var a1_Events = [function1, function2, function3, function5, function6, function7, function8],
        a1_c = 0;
    function function1() {
        alert('Click 1!');
    }
    function function2() {
        alert('Click 2!');
    }
    function function3() {
        $("#area1").hide();
        $("#area2").show();
        alert('Click 3!');

    }
    function function5() {
        alert('Click 4!');
    }
    function function6() {
        $("#bg_div").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
        $("#bg_skew").show(0).delay(1500).hide(0);
        alert('Click 5!');

    }
    function function7() {
        alert('Click 6!');
    }
    function function8() {
        $("#area1").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
        $("#area2").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
        $("#sound1").show(0).delay(4500).hide(0);

            document.getElementById("id1").play(); // OK..

        $("#hammer").show(0).delay(1500).hide(0);
        $("#youwin").show(0).delay(3500).hide(0);
        alert('Click 7!');


    }
    $('#area1').click(function () {
        a1_Events[a1_c++ % a1_Events.length]();
    });
    $("#area2").click(function () {
        $("#area1").show();
        $("#area2").hide();
          alert('Click 8!');
    });
});

function alert(msg) {
    $("#alert").text(msg).show(0).delay(1500).hide(0);
}
```

On a former project -- Defining custom cuepoints within a Video; I found a solution to neatly call and declare the custom cuepoints as below; it would be **COOL** (http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cool) if I could do something similar with CLICKS; and organize my current functions to neatly appear per click similar as I did with the cuepoints so I can easily add functions per; and update what happens per click

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Slides object with a time (integer) and a html string
var slides = {
0: "This is the first subtitle. You can put html in here if you like",
4: "A fluffy thing eating some grass.",
12: "Oh look it's a castle on a hill. Nice",
23: "Some horses",
34: "Wow look at those woolly sheep eating grass.",
40: "For more information on this plugin visit github/owainlewis or email owain@owainlewis.com",
50: "Cuepoint.js is an open source plugin for adding subtitles and cue-points to your HTML5 video"
}
```

Comment: In `function3` you show `#area2` which has a click event bound to it, and then you click on `#area2` triggering the click event. Which alerts Click 8.

Comment: after reading your comments I realized what you really need, I've edited my answer, have a look and let me know if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you should do to have your functions execute in the right order/after n amount of clicks you could do the following:

First, instead of storing the references to your functions in an array, store them in a hash, like this:

```
    var a1_Events = {
      1: function1, 
      3: function2, 
      7: function3, 
      12: function5, 
      20: function6, 
      23: function7, 
      30: function8
    },
    a1_c = 0;
```

setting the number to the amount of clicks the function should execute. And then in your click handler additionally to increment the click count in `al_c` you do:

```
    $('#area1').click(function () {
      al_c++;
      if (a1_Events[al_c] !== undefined) {
        al_Events[al_c]();
      }
    });
```

basically you increment the click count, and then you try to lookup if there is a function in your hash corresponding to the amount of clicks, if there is one you execute it.

With this solution you can easily add functions to your hash like:

```
al_Events[33] = function12;
```

and also remove them:

```
delete al_Events[3];
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: @intutivepixel thanks a lot for the response!! But it appears so in the jsfiddle that you sent; these functions don't fire onClick but rather as the page loads; and automatically. It's completely different and out of context.

Comment: @1977, yes, the jsbin provided was only conceptual on how to go about such tasks using javascript in a more robust way, it was not meant to be a full solution but only to show a different approach

Comment: Alright, thanks for this thought; but I am in the exact same place as when I wrote that question.

Comment: @1977 edited my answer to reflect more your use case, have a look